# Updating a ManyToMany relationship to include a new field

Tags: java, spring, java-8, set, spring-data

So, I've got an existing ManyToMany relationship set up in my spring application.  It appears that I made a mistake by setting this up using the @ManyToMany annotation, because now I need to add a field to the join table, and this does not appear to be an easy feat.

My structure is shipments and products.  The shipment table stores information about who the shipment was sent to, what date it was sent, etc.  The product table stores information about the product, who makes it, description, size, etc.

What I failed to consider when building this out was, I will need to track quantity of product shipped when I create a shipment, which should be done on the join table.

I've been working along with this example: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

UPDATE:
I've been working through the example above and have run into an issue with infinite recursive calls between the product and shipment tables.  My structure is as follows:

ShipmentProductID.java:

```
// Package and Imports here

@Embeddable
public class ShipmentProductId
    implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "product_id")
private Long productId;

@Column(name = "shipment_id")
private Long shipmentId;

private ShipmentProductId() {}

public ShipmentProductId(
        Long productId,
        Long shipmentId) {
    this.productId = productId;
    this.shipmentId = shipmentId;
}

// Getters and Setters here

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;

    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;

    ShipmentProductId that = (ShipmentProductId) o;
    return Objects.equals(productId, that.productId) &&
            Objects.equals(shipmentId, that.shipmentId);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(productId, shipmentId);
}
}
```

ShipmentProduct.java:

```
// Package and Imports here

@Entity(name = "ShipmentProduct")
@Table(name = "shipment_product")
public class ShipmentProduct {

@EmbeddedId
private ShipmentProductId id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId("productId")
private Product product;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId("shipmentId")
private Shipment shipment;

@Column(name = "created_on")
private Date createdOn = new Date();

private ShipmentProduct() {}

public ShipmentProduct(Product product, Shipment shipment) {
    this.product = product;
    this.shipment = shipment;
    this.id = new ShipmentProductId(product.getId(), 
    shipment.getId());
}

// Getters and Setters here

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;

    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        return false;

    ShipmentProduct that = (ShipmentProduct) o;
    return Objects.equals(product, that.product) &&
            Objects.equals(shipment, that.shipment);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(product, shipment);
}
}
```

Product.java:

```
// Package and Imports here

@Entity
@Data
@Cache( usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE )
public class Product extends AbstractEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@JsonIgnoreProperties("products")
// Have tried @JsonIgnore as well
@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "product",
        orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<ShipmentProduct> shipments = new ArrayList<>();

@NotNull
private Integer quantity;

public boolean isAssociated(Client client){
    if( this.client == null || this.client.getId() == null ||
            client == null || client.getId() == null ) return 
false;
    return this.client.getId() == client.getId();
}

public boolean isAssociated(Expression expression){
    if( this.expression == null || this.expression.getId() == null 
||
            expression == null || expression.getId() == null ) 
return false;
    return this.expression.getId() == expression.getId();
}

public void addShipment(Shipment shipment) {
    ShipmentProduct shipmentProduct = new ShipmentProduct(this, 
shipment);
    shipments.add(shipmentProduct);
    shipment.getProducts().add(shipmentProduct);
}

public Set<Shipment> getAllShipments(){
    Set<Shipment> shipmentList = new HashSet<>();
    for (ShipmentProduct shipmentProduct : shipments) {
        shipmentList.add(shipmentProduct.getShipment());
    }
    return shipmentList;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Product product = (Product) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, product.id);
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "";
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id);
}
}
```

Shipment.java:

```
// Package and Imports here

@Entity
@Data
@ToString(exclude = {"products", "contacts"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"products", "contacts"})
public class Shipment extends AbstractEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@JsonIgnoreProperties("shipments")
@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "shipment",
        orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<ShipmentProduct> products = new ArrayList<>();

public Set<Product> getAllProducts(){
    Set<Product> productList = new HashSet<>();
    for (ShipmentProduct shipmentProduct : products) {
        productList.add(shipmentProduct.getProduct());
    }
    return productList;
}

public void addProduct(Product product) {
    ShipmentProduct shipmentProduct = new ShipmentProduct(product, 
this);
    products.add(shipmentProduct);
    product.getShipments().add(shipmentProduct);
}

public void removeProduct(Product product) {
    for (Iterator<ShipmentProduct> iterator = products.iterator();
         iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        ShipmentProduct shipmentProduct = iterator.next();

        if (shipmentProduct.getShipment().equals(this) &&
                shipmentProduct.getProduct().equals(product)) {
            iterator.remove();

shipmentProduct.getProduct().getShipments().remove(shipmentProduct);
            shipmentProduct.setShipment(null);
            shipmentProduct.setProduct(null);
        }
    }
}

public Optional<Product> getProductById(Long productId){
    Optional<ShipmentProduct> shipmentProduct = 
products.stream().filter(product -> 
product.getId().equals(productId)).findFirst();
    return productId == null ? Optional.empty() :
            Optional.of(shipmentProduct.get().getProduct());
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Shipment shipment = (Shipment) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, shipment.id);
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "";
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id);
}
}
```

It seems like I'm getting close, as this appears to be working aside from creating an infinitely large JSON object.  I've tried all sorts of combinations of EAGER vs LAZY and JsonIgnore and JsonIgnoreProperties.  Any thoughts on how to resolve this?  My best guess is some interaction with Lombok, but I have not been able to figure this out.

Comment: A lot of work? You need to add table with two columns, right?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, I would need to change my ManyToMany relationships to ManyToOne relationships, create the join tables for that, then update my services and controllers to utilize the new join table in order to utilize CRUD operations for my shipments and products.

Comment: Or use `@JoinTable`

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?  I'm still very new to Spring.  Can I keep my current ManyToMany relationship and simply tack on a table to track quantities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I finally figured this out... I removed the following methods:

```
getAllProducts()
getAllShipments()
```

and replaced them with:

```
allProducts()
allShipments()
```

Having them as getters was always adding them to my return object, and they were not being cut off by @JsonIgnore, or anything else.

Next, I updated ShipmentProduct.java and added ***@JsonIgnore*** to both shipment and product, while removing ***@JsonIgnore*** and/or ***@JsonIgnoreProperties*** from Shipment.java and Product.java.

Then, in order to not receive errors when utilizing allProducts() or allShipments(), I added this to my application.properties file: ***spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false***

Once this was all complete, I was also able to keep lombok.

Hopefully this helps somebody else in a similar situation.  Also, if anybody has additional constructive criticism, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You can keep `@ManyToMany` annotation, just add the joining table in your db and map it:

```
@JoinTable(
        name = "joining_table",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "this_id_in_jt",
                referencedColumnName = "this_id"
        ),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "other_id_in_jt",
                referencedColumnName = "other_id"
        )
)
@ManyToMany
private List<Other> others;
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I have now, I guess the piece I'm not quite getting is how then, do I utilize the new field in that join table?  I'm sorry if this is a dense question, I'm just not fully understanding how I can add quantity to "joining_table", and pull that data here?

Comment: joining table has only ids of those two entities, data is saved, when the association between them is created

Comment: Right, but I need to track how many of each product was included with each shipment, which I presume I will need to be added to that join table?

Comment: Ehh, you're mapping it to list, right? In my case `orders.size()`.

Comment: Could you, please, read some article about it? Like that: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ Then if you have problems, ask a question with specific error. If you find this answer helpful, consider upvoting / marking as correct.